# How can i know the occurrences of the value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
dict_data = {'1-0': [5400, 3601],
 '1-1': [2550, 1651],
 '1-3': [5400, 3601],
 '1-4': [5400, 3601],
 '1-5': [5400, 3601],
 '10-0': [3601, 2700]}
```

In this example the output i'd like to get is all the values so the output for this example should be a list of lists giving these values when printing all its elements, basically the value should occur only once in that list of lists we will create now matter how many times it appears as value or keys in `dict_data`:

```
[2550, 1651]
[5400, 3601]
[3601, 2700]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are not hashable, so why not use a loop:

```
L = []
for v in dict_data.values():
    if v not in L:
        L.append(v)
```

Comment: This works but is O(n^2) complexity whereas the set method is O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
set(map(tuple, dict_data.values()))
```

Output from your example:

```
{(2550, 1651), (3601, 2700), (5400, 3601)}
```

This loses no information as compared to a list of lists but if you do need it in that format then you can do:

```
[list(t) for t in set(map(tuple, dict_data.values()))]
```

outputs

```
[[5400, 3601], [2550, 1651], [3601, 2700]]
```

Comment: Got this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @Talar Ah you caught me before my edit. Will work now.

Comment: Are you sure? Works on my machine in python 3.6

Comment: Odd i'm using python 3.5 and i get `[list(t) for t in set(map(tuple, my_dict.values()))]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Is your example representative of your actual data? Do you have nested lists?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in linear time if you keep a set of what has been seen:

```
seen = set()
for v in dict_data.values():
    curr = tuple(v)
    if curr not in seen:
        seen.add(curr)

print(list(seen))
```

Which Outputs:

```
[(5400, 3601), (2550, 1651), (3601, 2700)]
```

Comment: Why create the list simultaneously? Just call `list` on `seen` at the end (if OP even really needs to)?

Comment: Just to facilitate the wisdom of the crowd - this approach was the fastest using a dictionary with 10000 random entries and `timeit`.

Comment: @Piinthesky Yeah seems to be. Although I think in this case, the OP was looking for the most straightforward approach, like your answer. I don't he/she was too concerned with efficiency.